How to cache and multicast Flux without prefetching whole sequence?
Given a Flux with potentially infinite elements and multiple subscribers which want to get elements from the beginning, what operator do I need to connect them together?
Generating these elements is expensive (eg. http call for ~20 of them), so over-producing is highly undesirable. All subscribers need to start from first element and finish when they want (.take, rsocket, etc), so one subscriber could take only 1-20 elements, while another would take 1-100. So, in this example I expect only first 100 elements to be cached, while being able to continue it if another subscriber wants 200 elements.
The problem is that after transforming the publisher to hot one it won't account for actual requested amount, producing as fast as it can.
What I've tried already:

.cached() force max demand, even if subscribers only want fixed amount of elements. After subscriber's cancellation publisher continues to produce new elements (but no one asked for them?)
.replay().refCount() cancels publisher if there are no alive subscribers, effectively restarting it on future subscribers, so it can't be used for caching sequence. Another background subscriber leads to same problem of over-producing elements without real demand for them.
moving "cache" from top level to request level (where pages of elements are loaded) - it surely works, but breaks ability to control such sequences along multiple implementations (eg. r2dbc returns full Flux already, so I need to paginate it and cache pages then).
Sinks. I haven't found a way to connect source flux to sink without overproducing.

So, something like .cache(Integer.MAX_VALUE, prefetch: 20) is needed but I don't know how to do it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
